# parse HTML table row using regular expression

Tags: html, regex

i have gone though this post [why not use regular expression for HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). As a part of the task given to me, i had no choice but to use regular expression for HTML.

i have HTML code and separately tried like

```
 <td class="a-nowrap">

          <span class="a-letter-space"></span><span>13</span>

        </td>
```

i have been able to get the **13** using following regular expression :

```
<td class="a-nowrap">\s*<span class="a-letter-space"></span><span>(\d*)</span>\s*</td>
```

and similarly 
from

```
<td class="a-nowrap">

          <a class="a-link-normal" title="69% of reviews have 5 stars" href="">5 star</a><span class="a-letter-space"></span>          

        </td>
```

got 5 **star** using the regular expression

```
<td class="a-nowrap">\s*<a class="a-link-normal" [^>]*>\s*(.*)</a>\s*</td>
```

But when both of the HTML code is combined like,

```
<table id="histogramTable" class="a-normal a-align-middle a-spacing-base">

  <tr class="a-histogram-row">



        <td class="a-nowrap">

          <a class="a-link-normal" title="69% of reviews have 5 stars" href="">5 star</a><span class="a-letter-space"></span>          

        </td>

        <td class="a-span10">

          <a class="a-link-normal" title="69% of reviews have 5 stars" href=""><div class="a-meter"><div class="a-meter-bar" style="width: 69.1358024691358%;"></div></div></a>

        </td>

        <td class="a-nowrap">

          <span class="a-letter-space"></span><span>13</span>

        </td>

  </tr>
  <td class="a-nowrap">

      <a class="a-link-normal" title="2% of reviews have 1 stars" href="">1 star</a><span class="a-letter-space"></span>          

    </td>

    <td class="a-span10">

      <a class="a-link-normal" title="2% of reviews have 1 stars" href=""><div class="a-meter"><div class="a-meter-bar" style="width: 2.46913580246914%;"></div></div></a>

    </td>

    <td class="a-nowrap">

      <span class="a-letter-space"></span><span>2</span>

    </td>


</table>
```

how to extract **5 star and 13**  using regular expression?

Comment: updated my answer with new shorter regex, which works for the modified input you have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use HTML parser, use one regex after another or add `.*`this between two patterns, I have modified a bit your **star** regex as it didn't work properly:

First enable **dotall** flag (s) and then use this:

```
<td class="a-nowrap">\s*<a class="a-link-normal" [^>]*>\s*(\d star).*<td class="a-nowrap">\s*<span class="a-letter-space"></span><span>(\d*)</span>\s*</td>
```

**Output:**

> Group 1: 5 star
>
> Group 2: 13

**EDIT:**

I have made shorter regex:

**REGEX:**

```
>(\d star)<.+?>(\d+?)<
```

Which used on [pythonregex.com](http://www.pythonregex.com) with the edited input you have provided gives:

**OUTPUT:**

```
>>> regex.findall(string)
[(u'5 star', u'13'), (u'1 star', u'2')]
```

Comment: using above expression, it will be like [('5 star', ''), ('', '13')]  but i want something like [('5 star', '13')], '|' or expression making this trouble. any idea on that?

Comment: @naveenyadav that's strange as I use the patterns you have provided, just added **OR** between them, so the pattern will catch either ** 5 stars** and/or *13*. Do these patterns work for you when you use them separately?

Comment: @naveenyadav well so you almost get what you want : ) ok so let me think a bit.

Comment: @naveenyadav well you get that output as it matches both cases, but you have both results you wanted, so you could use them as you wished right? Unfortunately I'm not able to check how does this regex work properly as I have never used regex for HTML : (

Comment: @naveenyadav I would help further but I am unable to check the results. I would suggest you to maybe add `.*` instead of `|` it might help.

Comment: @naveenyadav I have modified my answer, in the site (pythonregex.com) you have provided it gives following output: [(u'5 star', u'13')]. (remember to enable dot all flag)

Comment: yes i checked it was working , Thanks. But when i have added one <tr> data in above HTML snippet. it is fetching the values from one <tr> only. I have changed the Html snippet.

Comment: code is working fine. I appreciate your effort to help me out. thanks